# About the RsaSHA256Signer and thread safety for Google Wallet

Tags: android-pay

Is the RsaSHA256Signer thread safe and reusable or is it intended to be one-time use only?

Comment: Which same manner? Can you please explain in more detail what you're asking, would love to help out but need more info :) Also please let us know which Google Wallet API you're using. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes RsaSHA256Signer is thread safe and reusable.  It uses java.security.Signature to create the signature.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html